# Python pip install fails: invalid command egg_info

Tags: python, pip

I find that recently often when I try to install a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) package using *[pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29)*, I get the error(s) below.

I found a reference online that one has to use "*python2 setup.py install*" from the download directory, and indeed find that this will then work if I manually find and download the package (from pypi).

But, I don't know where pip is downloading packages to, and/or why it is failing in this manner.

I tried to do a pip upgrade, but it also failed in a similar manner, with a bunch of "Unknown distribution option" errors (entry_points, zip_safe, test_suite, tests_require)!

- pip 1.0.1
- [ActivePython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePython) 2.7

Trying to use ActiveState's pypm fails, because they have a smaller library base, and it doesn't include these packages.

```
C:\test>pip install requests-oauth
Downloading/unpacking requests-oauth
  Downloading requests-oauth-0.4.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests-oauth
    E:\Plang\ActivePython\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    E:\Plang\ActivePython\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    E:\Plang\ActivePython\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)

E:\Plang\ActivePython\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: invalid command 'egg_info'
```

Comment: For me it worked installing `python-dev`

Answer (score 332, accepted):

<s>Install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6#installation-instructions), which comes with `egg_info`.</s>

Should be as simple as `pip install Distribute`.

Distribute has been merged into Setuptools as of version 0.7. If you are using a version <=0.6, upgrade using `pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `easy_install -U setuptools`.

Comment: doesnt work for me. I have distribute installed, but still get the egg info error almost every time I try to install a package

Comment: To those like @Zorpix who still get errors you might want to checking what version of pip you're calling.  On Ubuntu I found that I had a distro-packaged version that was still getting called.

Comment: For the new version of setuptools to work, you might also have to uninstall distribute by hand or by deleting `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-*`

Comment: if you still have problems after removing distribute or pip doesn't upgrade setuptools properly, try `easy_install -U setuptools` This worked for me.

Comment: Oddly, this fixed the error for all installs **except** `pip install -U pip`.

Comment: that's not work for me,I solve it by `sudo python ez_setup.py`

Comment: Thanks! Ran into this when running pip install aws. The error is annoying because it says it's a paramiko error.

Comment: It may seem obvious, but ensure your `$PATH` is set correctly. I am using virtualenv and got this error when the package I was trying to install couldn't find a dependency in `$PATH`. In my case, I was trying to install `psycopg2`, but hadn't specified the bin directory of my Postgres installation. [This question addresses my case specifically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170895/mac-virtualenv-pip-postgresql-error-pg-config-executable-not-found).

Comment: i had a similar problem, here is the answer to the related (duplicate ?) question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42803623/880128

Comment: Just had similar problem in a gcp vm when a tried install google-cloud module. Your answer solved it! Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the message:  "Requirement already up-to-date"

Answer (score 60):

As distribute has been merged back into setuptools, it is now recommended to install/upgrade setuptools instead:

```
[sudo] pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: For some reason I had to run this twice (in my virtual env I had distribute 0.6.49 and setuptools 0.6c11) and then I could install the latest version of pip without problems.

Comment: @glarrain it happened to me to! thanks for the heads up! the first pass uninstalled distribute 0.7, and the second uninstalled setuptools 0.6c11

Answer (score 22):

Bear in mind you may have to do `pip install --upgrade Distribute` if you have it installed already and your `pip` may be called `pip2` for Python2 on some systems (it is on mine).

Comment: As a note, this must be done in administrator mode on Windows for a typical Python installation. Otherwise, it is easy to overlook an installation failure for Distribute.

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue, as well as some other issues with Brewed Python on [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks).

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

didn't work for me, and I think my setuptools/distribute setup was botched.

I finally got it to work by running

```
sudo easy_install -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 11):

None of the above worked for me on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) LTS (Precise Pangolin), and here's how I fixed it in the end:

Download **ez_setup.py** from [download setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (see "Installation Instructions" section) then:

```
$ sudo python ez_setup.py
```

I hope it saves someone some time.

Answer (score 9):

This error can occur when you trying to install `pycurl`.

In this case you should do

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev
```

(founded here: https://gist.github.com/lxneng/1031014 )

Answer (score 8):

On CentOS 6.5, the short answer from a clean install is:

`yum -y install python-pip
pip install -U pip
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U setuptools`

You are not seeing double, you must run the setuptools upgrade twice. The long answer is below:

Installing the `python-pip` package using yum brings `python-setuptools` along as a dependency. It's a pretty old version and hence it's actually installing `distribute (0.6.10)`. After installing a package manager we generally want to update it, so we do `pip install -U pip`. Current version of pip for me is 1.5.6.

Now we go to update setuptools and this version of pip is smart enough to know it should remove the old version of distribute first. It does this, but then instead of installing the latest version of setuptools it installs `setuptools (0.6c11)`.

At this point all kinds of things are broken due to this extremely old version of setuptools, but we're actually halfway there. If we now run the exact same command a second time, `pip install -U setuptools`, the old version of setuptools is removed, and version 5.5.1 is installed. I don't know why pip doesn't take us straight to the new version in one shot, but this is what's happening and hopefully it will help others to see this and know you're not going crazy.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the default easy_install is broken in its current location:

`$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install`

A way to overcome this is to use the easy_install in site packages. For example:

`$ sudo python /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/easy_install.py boto`

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue and I tried all the above answers. But unfortunately, none of the above worked.

As a note, I finally solve this by `pip uninstall distribute`.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Turned out I had an old verison of distribute installed, and an even older version of setuptools installed and being preferred over the newer setuptools installed by my system packager... Uninstalling both setuptools and distribute, and then re-installing setuptools using my system packager fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older question but here are the steps I used to get `cassandra-driver` to actually install on Windows 7 / Python2. <s>I have windows 10 / Python3 at home where I will test this tonight.</s> I have confirmed this also works on Windows 10 with both Python 2 and 3.

**Problem**

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\Frito\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-7dgmdc\cassandra-driver
```

**TL;DR Solution**

- Installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7)

**Solution** (I'd love for someone to explain why this worked)

- Attempted `pip install cassandra-driver` and got the above error message
- Attempted `pip install --pre cassandra-driver` and got the following error

> ```
> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
> Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
>
> Command "c:\users\Frito\.virtualenvs\symdash\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\Frito\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-sesxxu\\cassandra-driver\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record  c:\users\Frito\appdata\local\temp\pip-ujsxsk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\Frito\.virtualenvs\symdash\include\site\python2.7\cassandra-driver"  failed with error code 1 in  c:\users\Frito\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-sesxxu\cassandra-driver
> ```

- Installed `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7`
- Successfully executed `pip install --pre cassandra-driver`
- Successfully executed `pip uninstall cassandra-driver`
- Successfully executed `pip install cassandra-driver`

To reiterate, I'm not really sure why this worked. Right now my two leading conclusions are that either the C++ compiler is required *or* that running the `--pre` option the first time installed some dependencies that were missing from the 'regular' install. I'll update tonight after work when I have more details.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install -U setuptools` and `easy_install` was putting egg-info in the wrong directory.

Then I just reinstalled `apt-get install python-dev`.
Let me install the drivers I want after that

Answer (score 1):

try the following command:

```
pip install setuptools==28.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just convert liquidki's answer into Ubuntu commands. On an Ubuntu based system it works!:

```
sudo apt -y install python-pip
pip install -U pip
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading pip from 8.1.1 to 9.0.1 solved this problem.

You can run something like `sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade your pip version.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet a similar error message 
"Command 'python setup.py egg_info' failed with error code 1"
when I want to install **cairosvg** with command `pip install cairosvg` in a virtual environment.

Then I have tried both `pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install --upgrade setuptools` before running `pip3 install cairosvg`, but I still get this error.

I can get rid of this error with **sudo** in front of the installation command : `sudo pip install cairosvg`.
But note that the command with **sudo** will install the package for the system python rather than the virtual environment.

So, I further check the error message and find that I get the error while installing the **cairocffi**. Then I install a certain version of cairocffi ([refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35172496/6384650)) before install cairosvg. That is how I solve my problem.