# Unable to install evernote sdk for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, evernote

I'm trying to install the evernote sdk for python.

- I'm running windows 7.
- And I have Python version 3.3.2
- I just started learning python 3 days ago. :)
- I'm getting this error

What am I doing wrong? or what other information do you need to help me?

---

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "c:\users\anthony\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Anthony\evernote\setup.py" , line 6

exec x

         ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know current version of Evernote SDK does not support Python 3. There is expermiental Evernote SDK for Python 3 available at [github](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3)

Comment: Thanks. I installed version Python version 2.7.5. And had a few problems which I was able to fix by following this answer about pip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info. Now everything works fine.