# How to run Python web application in local(Windows)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just download a web application which written using Python.
Im completely new to Python. After i do some research, below is what i have done

1) Install Python 2.7

2) Install pip ([How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/16377781#16377781))

When i try to run the python file by using this command

```
Python PATH/test.py
```

It show

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PATH\test.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Blueprint, flash, request, render_template
```

Python Code:

```
from flask import Blueprint, flash, request, render_template
from steam import vdf
import json

vdfjson = Blueprint("vdfjson", __name__, template_folder="templates")


@vdfjson.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
response = None
format = "json"
if request.method == "POST":
    format = request.form["format"]
    data = request.form["data"]

    try:
        if format == "vdf":
            response = json.dumps(
                vdf.loads(data),
                indent=4
            )

        elif format == "json":
            _response = json.loads(data)
            response = vdf.dumps(_response).decode("utf-16")

    except ValueError:
        flash("ValueError:  Your {} may not be valid.".format(format), "danger")
        response = "{}" if format == "json" else ""

return render_template("vdfjson.html", response=response, format=format, title="vdfjson")
```

*It is a web application, so im not sure whether i follow the right instruction or not.

I try to install flask

```
pip install flask
```

and i get below error

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install Flask
Downloading/unpacking Flask
Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB): 544kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package Flask
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'include_package_data'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: invalid command 'egg_info'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'include_package_data'

warnings.warn(msg)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
'zip_safe'

warnings.warn(msg)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
'install_requires'

warnings.warn(msg)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
'test_suite'

warnings.warn(msg)

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

or: -c --help-commands

or: -c cmd --help



error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sam\appdat
a\local\temp\pip_build_SAM\Flask
Storing complete log in C:\Users\SAM\pip\pip.log

C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

After that i execute again

```
Python PATH/test.py
```

it did not show any error but do nothing.

Comment: Do you have `Blueprint` installed? Try running `pip install blueprint`.

Comment: Blueprint is a Flask module, there is no need to install it seperatly.

Comment: Also, I didn't found module called steam. Be sure, that you have it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a complete flask application. You need to make Flask instance and then register your blueprint in it. Try to run the code below:

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask, flash, request, render_template
from steam import vdf
import json
app = Flask(__name__)


vdfjson = Blueprint("vdfjson", __name__, template_folder="templates")
app.register_blueprint(vdfjson)


@vdfjson.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    response = None
    format = "json"
    if request.method == "POST":
        format = request.form["format"]
        data = request.form["data"]

        try:
            if format == "vdf":
                response = json.dumps(
                    vdf.loads(data),
                    indent=4
                )

            elif format == "json":
                _response = json.loads(data)
                response = vdf.dumps(_response).decode("utf-16")

        except ValueError:
            flash("ValueError:  Your {} may not be valid.".format(format), "danger")
            response = "{}" if format == "json" else ""

        return render_template("vdfjson.html", response=response, format=format, title="vdfjson")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Blueprint, Flask, flash, request, render_template
ImportError: No module named flask

Comment: That means, you don't have flask, so you have to install it.

Comment: I get some error during installation of flask. Please refer to the updated post.

Comment: Ok. Right now. After i execute "Python PATH/test.py" it did not show any error but do nothing. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install flask (and possibly some other libraries). Start with flask and see what errors you get after.

```
pip install flask
```

Often there's a requirements.txt file with the project that has the list of dependencies. You can then just run:

```
pip install -r ./path_to/requirements.txt
```

Which will install them all for you. Once you're more comfortable look into virtualenv which will allow you to create isolated environments for installing your libraries on a per project basis.

Comment: I get some error during installation of flask. Please refer to the updated post.

Comment: Looks like you have some issue with the setup tools. Apparently you need to run 'pip install --upgrade setuptools' (then try again).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info

Comment: Thanks. I re run using "Python PATH/test.py" this time no more error but nothing show.

Comment: Sounds like now you want to try @Alexander Zhukov's solution above. The test.py that you showed us is for a Blueprint - it's like a submodule of an application that expects to be included in something bigger. You really need the application itself. I have no idea what the project is but I would have thought there would be a main application file with it somewhere.

Comment: Just to add - once it's running it should look the terminal has frozen and you'll be able to access it in your web browser by going to localhost:5000

Answer (score 1):

The author has update the latest version of the original source source.
So it work right now. Case closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You successfully run your `test.py`,
however libraries

> from flask import Blueprint, flash, request, render_template

you try to import is not in [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Means that the library file is missing? Is there any way to check the path of my libraries?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

pip install -u setuptools

pip install flask