# install psycopg02 from PyCharm error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to add psycopg02 package to a Django project which using virtualenv.

I'm new in Python/Django development and also new to Apple Mac OS X.

Please find a screenshot of the error [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/grenny50132arij/Screenshot%202014-12-02%2011.29.04.png?dl=0)

Comment: Pycharm did it via pip like the attached screenshot shows...

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL installed on your machine?

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170895/mac-virtualenv-pip-postgresql-error-pg-config-executable-not-found) question

Comment: If you want to install psycopg2 package in virtualenv you have to have pythonX-dev package installed. where X is either 2 or 3, depending on which python you are using. Thats what i have to do under Ubuntu anyway. No idea if this is helpful to you.

Comment: Is this because I'm linking my global python with my virutalenv? if yes so how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this by installing EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL and create the virtualenv through Terminal instead of PyCharm