# Cant find pg_config even after installing Postgres 9.5

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pip, fink

I have been trying to debug this for quite a while now (and read lots of related Q/A on StackOverflow) but unable to figure this out.

Trying to setup Django on my Mac OS X 10.11.6. I followed the detailed [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/install/). This is what I did:

1) Installed Python 3.5.2 (by directly downloading the package from the Python web site and running it).

2) Installed PostGres 9.5 using the fink package (`fink install postgresql95`)

3) Installed psycopg2 using the fink package (`fink install psycopg2-py35`).

4) Updated pip.

5) Setup a virtual environment and activated it.

6) After activating the environment, installed Django (via pip).

Next, when I tried to setup a sample app in the environment and ran `python manage.py migrate`, it gave me the error : Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

After reading a lot of posts on StackOverflow, it seemed that I have to install psycopg2 again *within* the virtualenv (and for some reason, I cant use Fink again?). So as suggested on some posts, I tried to install it using:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Got this error:`Error: pg_config executable not found.`

I am sure my Fink install of Postgres 9.5 was successful earlier, so I tried to search for pg_config from root dir:

```
sudo find . -name "pg_config"
```

But it returned nothing!

My question is, is it possible that fink package did not come with pg_config? If it didnt, is my only option now to uninstall postgres and install it with another package? (FYI: I was able to start PostGres and create a user and a database on it already)

Thanks in advance,
Anupam

**Update:** After waiting a while to get answers from SO, I gave up and just uninstalled the postgres fink package. Then installed the postgres.app instead, on my mac. Working fine for me. The command `python manage.py migrate` worked fine for me this time and the psycopg2 installation also went fine (with pip). I wonder why the psycopg2 installation page (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#installation) only mentions Fink and MacPorts as the installation options especially when the Fink packages dont seem to be very reliable. I had posted a message on the Fink users group also about improving the installation documentation in another context but didnt get a response : (

Comment: try `sudo find / -name pg_config` if it returns an existing path, then export that path as an `environment variable`. I am not familiar with mac os. In ubuntu I do export in `.bashrc` file. In mac I think it is `/etc/profile`.

Comment: tried that - returned nothing still : (

Comment: In case you are using postgres.app refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170895/mac-virtualenv-pip-postgresql-error-pg-config-executable-not-found

Comment: not using postgres.app. Just installed a Fink package