# heroku local web :error No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, heroku

My project was running until I tried to test with `heroku` for deploy.
So I installed `virtualenv` and added a requirements.txt file with:

```
appdirs==1.4.0
packaging==16.8
Django==1.9.7
pyparsing==2.1.10
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
```

I changed django to 1.8.5 thinking it might be version related.
When I pip installed `requirements.txt`, I got this error:

> Error: pg_config executable not found.
>   Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PAT
>   or specify the full executable path with the option:
>
> python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
>       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

Comment: your error might be replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170895/mac-virtualenv-pip-postgresql-error-pg-config-executable-not-found try this.

Comment: i installed postgres following the answers in replica above ,but still have an error