# pg 1.0.0 `fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, clang

*An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue*

I have an issue with the bundle install and cannot complete the installation.

What can I do to finish the bundle?

```
  find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

    --------------------

    find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

    "clang -o conftest -I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib -L. -L/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include "ruby.h"
    2: 
    3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
    4: {
    5:   return 0;
    6: }
    /* end */

        "clang -E -I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17 - 
             I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby- 
         2.4.0/ruby/backward - 
         I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. - 
         I/Users/leotyndall/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE - 
         D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno- 
         error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
         conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
         #include <libpq-fe.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
         1 error generated.
         checked program was:
         /* begin */
         1: #include "ruby.h"
         2: 
         3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
        /* end */

    --------------------


     extconf failed, exit code 1


        An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
        Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Try to user lower version of pg, say pg -v '0.18' in your Gemfile

Comment: It's probably something with your `$PATH` setup. Can you past the output of `echo "${PATH//:/\n}"` in your terminal? Also  your Gemfile ?

Comment: Moved most specific error message to title. Reformatted for clarity. Moved questions to top of text and rephrased for clarity.

Comment: I had a similar problem where pg_config could not be found and [This solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217329/1752417)

Answer (score 18):

For macos, the above answers did not work or were not practical for me. I didn't want to install all of postgres.

```
$ brew install libpq
$ bundle config --local build.pg --with-opt-dir="/usr/local/opt/libpq"
$ bundle install
```

Reference: https://michaelrigart.be/install-pg-ruby-gem-without-postgresql/

Answer (score 16):

Try installing `libpq-dev` or its equivalent for your OS:

- For Ubuntu systems: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`
- On [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RHEL) systems: `yum install postgresql-devel`
- For Mac [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29): `brew install postgresql`
- For Mac [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) PostgreSQL: `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql[version number]/bin/pg_config`
- For [OpenSuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE): `zypper in postgresql-devel`

Comment: On OSX (HeighSierra) I don't find how to install only postgres client. So you have to install postgresql (or simply postgres with brew) to obtain the needed file libpq-fe.h.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by installing the library

`brew install libpqxx`

Next, install pg normally... you can use gem

`gem install pg`

Answer (score 3):

```sh
brew install libpq

gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-pg-config=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/13.2/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: My local path was little different: `/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin/pg_config`, but otherwise this worked a charm. On Big Sur.