# pip issues - mac os 10.7.5

Tags: python, macos, pip

I've been struggling for a while trying to get pip to work correctly.

I have (I think) successfully installed pip, and when I run 'sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools,' I get the message that setuptools is up to date.

When I try to install a package, however, (in this case redis), I get the following error message:

```
error: invalid command 'egg_info'
```

In addition, the following is also printed:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lf/c8q5s8nd3h726l_x165442d80000gn/T/pip_build_Cbelden/redis
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Cbelden/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

### (Possible) Clues:

When running the 'which' command I noticed both pip and easy_install are in /usr/local/bin/ but python is in /usr/bin/. Could this cause some issues? Any help is appreciated.

As of now, there seem to be two Python installations in both /Library/Frameworks and in /System/Library/Frameworks (I do not know if this is normal or not).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python pip install fails: invalid command egg\_info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info)

Answer (score 0):

I backed up my system and upgraded to Mavericks. Whatever the new default Python distro is cleaned up any sort of crap I had installed earlier. I had an enthough distribution installed, which I think was the cause of my issues. pip now works successfully.