# error installing cryptography on centos

Tags: python-2.7

when I try to install Cryptography I have this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distributio
n option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distributio

    if not self.distribution.include_package_data:
AttributeError: Distribution instance has no attribute 'include_package_data'
```

I try to install it from pip & easy_install and same error

how can I fix it?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try getting rid of that first warning.

As said [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info): Distribute has been merged into Setuptools as of version 0.7. If you are using a version <=0.6, upgrade using

> `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

or

> `easy_install -U setuptools`

Comment: same error, I can't install just cryptography, other install working 100%