# error install Scipy in python 3.5.2

Tags: python, scipy, setuptools

I was trying to install the package Scipy in Python 3.5.2 but got the error message as below.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\erijs\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ydys9hb_\Scipy
```

I tried the suggested solution in [Python pip install fails: invalid command egg_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info#): upgrade setuptools and it shows that

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\progr
ams\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg
```

---

The command file I used to install the file is:

```
pip install scipy --log log.txt
```

The log file is provided below.

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.16.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 151, in run
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 10, in run
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in run
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link
        self._check_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 51, in _check_compiler
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 208, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 83, in _get_vc_env
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 237, in run_setup
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 267, in run
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 236, in runner
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\setup.py", line 264, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\setup.py", line 256, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1065, in run_setup
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 240, in run_setup
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 164, in save_modules
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 139, in resume
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\compat.py", line 65, in reraise
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 152, in save_modules
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 237, in run_setup
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 267, in run
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 236, in runner
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\setup.py", line 264, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\setup.py", line 256, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-irs__h0w\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-no48p2px\scipy\setup.py", line 253, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-no48p2px\scipy\setup.py", line 250, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 268, in __init__
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 638, in easy_install
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 668, in install_item
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 851, in install_eggs
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1079, in build_and_install
      File "c:\users\erijs\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1067, in run_setup
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\erijs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-no48p2px\scipy
```

Comment: You may want to add the commands you were running, also more of pip's log, not just the last line.

Comment: Thanks! log file provided!

Comment: What you want to google is `distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` - see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat
.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a try!

Comment: Note that using the binary wheels from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) are probably a good way to go for you. Compiling extension modules yourself on windows is always a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

From various hints obtained from here and elsewhere I found that renaming the file to: scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl allowed it to install.