# Failed to install "Cairocffi"

Tags: python, installation, pip, cairo, python-cffi

I'm working with python3, and i'm trying to install " **cairocffi**" on Ubuntu.
To do this, i've successfully installed:

1. python-dev
2. libffi-dev
3. cffi

But when i've trying to install "cairocffi" with `pip install cairocffi`,I got:

```
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 272
, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 261, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 327
, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line
 161, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line
 48, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line
 24, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "cairocffi/ffi_build.py", line 30, in <module>
        ffi.cdef(constants._CAIRO_HEADERS)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_CAIRO_HEADERS'

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-y0b_ir/cairocffi
```

Comment: The location of file */usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py* is odd. At the same time there is */usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py* so I guess you have installed *python3* ubuntu package but not *python3-setuptools*, and then *setuptools* in some other way. I tried to replicate your problem with xubuntu 12.04, there were no installation problems.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My problem is fixed by installing a specific version of cairocffi (version = 0.6)

```
pip install cairocffi==0.6
```

Comment: @zumma It did for me.

Comment: Well, that's all well and good, except I need 0.9.0... which still seems to give a similar error to this question.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into this today as well. Are you working through the Real Python course?

Anyway, to fix the problem, I installed the python 3 version of python-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo pip3 install cffi
sudo pip3 install cairocffi
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This fixs the issue when installing CairoSVG 2.1.3 in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: i also add: "python3-cffi libcairo2"

Answer (score 3):

install the libffi-dev package can fix this problem
simply run `sudo apt install libffi-dev`