# bzt 1.1.0 says DistributionNotFound: selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, taurus

I just installed bzt 1.1.0 on my MacOSX but it won't run, it gives this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bzt", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: selenium
```

The thing is, selenium 2.49.2 was installed along with bzt.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Python package management issue.  Selenium was installed in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages with a `selenium-2.49.2.dist-info` directory, not the `.egg-info` directory that `pkg_resources.py` expected.

Upgrading to a newer version of pkg_resources helped, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21175750/584846):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then, reinstalling selenium finally fixed the problem:

```
sudo pip uninstall selenium
sudo pip install selenium
```

Thanks to Andrey Pohilko on the [Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codename-taurus/xPBj3YJqRUw) for helping out.