# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing PyV8

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pyv8

I get the following error when installing [PyV8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/) using Python 2.7.10 on Windows:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\MyUsername\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-omxgan\pyv8
```

I ran

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

with success as it was recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info) and other threads but no luck. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Some mild investigations shows that PyV8 has a preview build for Python 2.7. It could be that pip is trying to install the Python 2.6 version? I can tell you my pip command is trying to install version 0.5 of pyv8, and I can't seem to force it to download 1.0