# egg_info error when installing python modules

Tags: python, macos, pip, installation

I am new to Python and I am trying to install [pypgen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypgen).

As explained one the webpage, I first installed "samtools" (via `brew install samtools` as recommended).

**Trying to install pypgen**

I tried the 4 ways suggested by the author to install `pypgen`

```
$pip3.6 install pypgen
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yv/n6rkh3sn5mn5qpsn87lvjw4m0000gp/T/pip-build-aQiBgg/pypgen/


$easy_install pypgen
Processing pypgen
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /Users/remi/Downloads/pypgen-0.2.1/pypgen


$pip3.6 install -e git+https://github.com/ngcrawford/pypgen.git
Could not detect requirement name, please specify one with #egg=
```

I downloaded "pypgen-0.2.1.tar.gz" from the [pypgen website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypgen), uncompressed it, `cd` to the folder and did

```
$python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    import distribute_setup
ImportError: No module named distribute_setup
```

So, I did

```
$pip3.6 install distribute
```

but it did not solve the previous issue

**Trying to Solve egg_info error**

This egg_info error seems to be key. I tried to download [this file](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py) and did

```
sudo python ez_setup.py
```

as recommended on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error) but it did not solve the error messages above. I then tried

```
sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade setuptools
```

as recommended on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info) but I keep receiving the same error messages when doing `pip3.6 install pypgen`

---

I am using Python 3.6 but I also have the version 2.7 installed. I tried everything with both versions (`pip3.6` and `pip2.7`) and get the same errors. I am on `MAC OS X 10.11.3`