# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ml9eeocq

Tags: python, pip

I want to simply install a package named **cpickle** with **pip3** but after running the command below:

```
sudo pip3 install cpickle
```

I got the following error:

```
Collecting cpickle
Downloading cpickle-0.5.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tokenize.py", line 438, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-cf2kl13q/cpickle/setup.py'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cf2kl13q/cpickle/
```

I've already read these links :
[stackoverflow-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info)
[stackoverflow-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)
[github](https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome/issues/4)
and so many others from the other communities but non of them worked for me.
Is it an unsolvable problem ?If it's not , then how can I solve the problem ?
I'm using **virtualenv**.