# Installing django-tables2 on heroku returning error: invalid command 'egg_info'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku, django-tables2

I'm trying to install django-tables2==1.21.1 on my Heroku dyno.  Below is the error logs when I try to install it:

```
~ $ pip install django-tables2
Collecting django-tables2
  Using cached django-tables2-1.21.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'extras_require'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'

    ----------------------------------------
```

The installation works fine on my local virtual env, I am running python 2.7.14 and django 1.11.11 on both.  All other packages install without any issues.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?
Thanks

Update:

Updating to python==3.6.4 and Django==2.0.3 fixed the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install fails: invalid command egg\_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info)

Comment: i tried those solutions, none of them worked unfortunately

Comment: Too bad! I have 0 experience with heroku, but if I can help in any way at the side of django-tables2, let me know using an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Same problem with `PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 (from awscli==1.15.5`, byt I already have python 3.6.4. and couldn't upgrade to Django 2 yet.