# Anaconda3 issues installing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow on Windows 10 using Anaconda3.

I get the following error message after every attempt.

```
 "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 
 3221226505 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
 8j_eg21o\termcolor\"
```

I Create a new Anaconda Container and tried running the following.

```
 "python -m pip install tensorflow"
 "python -m pip install tensorflow==1.7.1"
 "python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow"
```

There are some information on the internet stating my Setup Tools is out of date. I tried to correct this by using the Following commands.

```
 "pip install --upgrade setuptools"
 "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"
```

It does not correct the error message. Is there any Python Guru's that will be able to solve my issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why aren't you using pip3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda is there for such issues. You ought not use pip to install packages unless it is the last resort. conda helps you avoid colliding packages. Do:

```
conda update conda
conda create -n tensor python=3.6
```

We first updated conda, and then created an environment called tensor that has Python 3.6.

To activate our environment, install and test if we can use tensorflow, do:

```
conda activate tensor
conda config --append channels conda-forge
conda install tensorflow 
python -c "import tensorflow"
```

This activates our environment (tensor), appended conda-forge channel, install tensorflow and test if we can import tensorflow.

To add other packages e.g. jupyter, pandas and scikit-learn. We can do:

```
conda install -n tensor jupyter pandas scikit-learn
```

This works in or out of our tensor environment. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info), try upgrading setuptools via ,

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

Since you want to install TensorFlow in an Anaconda environment, I would suggest installing a Conda package. You can read the instructions [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages). Installing pip packages invite problems for some packages.
Install the [TensorFlow Conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) using,

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

The conda packages must work as expected.